# #include<vector> no such file or directory

Tags: iphone, stl, objective-c++

So I need to use vectors in my project. I have changed the .m file to .mm to make it Objective-C++. But, when I try saying:

```
#include <vector>
```

In my .h it says the file or directory can not be found. If I put that line of code though in my .mm file though the error doesn't appear, but since I need a vector in the `@interface` (which is in my .h) what should I do to make the .h file find the vector file?

Also, I have tried changing it to compiling everything as Objective-C++, but that doesn't work because I get some errors in the Cocos2d library I am using...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Is your .h file being included in any OTHER .h or .m files?

If so, you'll have to make those (or files including them, etc) into .mm as well.

Comment: So combine the .h and and .mm together?

Comment: Nope.  This particular header file (say x.h) naturally is included in x.mm, but presumably you're using objects of type x in some OTHER module as well, say y.  Therefore y.h will include the line "#include x.h".  Now when the compiler is compiling y.m, it will not be expecting C++ code, and so will complain about x.h's line "include <vector>" when it comes across it.  Therefore y.m must be renamed y.mm, even though you're not using any C++ code in y.mm  Finally, y.h may included in, say, z.h and you must convert z.m to z.mm, etc.  So it's easier to include the vector in the mm file if you can.

Comment: What to if same issue facing in Swift project.
Need to use ~ x.h in .swift file, but facing  "#include<vector> no such file or directory".

Any solution.

Comment: I had same problem. I created wrapper .mm file that I was able to import in {project}-Bridging-Header.h. Inside my wrapper file, I imported .h that had #include<vector>.

Comment: For Swifties, no; you cannot use an ObjC++ header from Swift. You'll need to create an ObjC-only header file around it (thus incorporating your vector.h or other c++ inside the associated .mm file)

Answer (score 8):

Without changing any .m to .mm or anything like that, if you click your project, click **tagets->build settings** go all the way down to **"LLVM GCC 4.2 - Languages"** you will see **Compile Sources As** change that value to **Objective-C++**;

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to upgrade to Xcode 11.1, so I trashed Xcode 11.0, then downloaded Xcode 11.1. Xcode 11.1 worked until I rebooted where I got the above message on the default "hello world" command line C++ program.

My solution was to:
quit Xcode,
empty the trash,
launch Xcode